# Precesion Error in C++, using double or float data type in for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, floating-point, double, codeblocks

So I encountered this weird issue that is self explanatory in this photo:[image: C++ program]

In the first 8 lines, I used a variable called `classwidth` to add increments to l which is set to have an initial value of `18.75`. Each iteration of the loop prints l value.

However in the second 8 lines, I do the same thing but, I replaced `classwidth` variable with a constant 1.68, the results are identical in the first 2 lines in each iteration, but in the second 8 lines the program calculates numbers correctly and as expected, while in the first 8 lines, the code starts to lose precession in the fourth line as shown in the photo.

I don't want to use a constant value of  1.68, because this value is calculated by range and k parameters, so it will not always be `1.68`.

What should I do to have the precession in the second eight lines while using constant `classwidth`?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//    cout << fixed;
//    cout << setprecision(2);
//    cout << 20.42 + 1.68*3 << endl;
    double range;
    double l;
    int k = 8;
    range = 32.17 -18.75;
    double classwidth = range/k;
    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    l = 18.75;
    for(int n = 1; n<=k ; n++){
        cout<< l << "                 classwidth: "<< classwidth<<endl;
        l += classwidth;




    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    l = 18.75;
    for(int n = 1; n<=k ; n++){
        cout<< l << "                 classwidth: "<< 1.68 <<endl;
        l += 1.68;



    }
    //groupedData();


}
```

I commented the

```
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
```

line of code so it is nonfunctional and I still didn't achieve what I want:
[image: C++ program]

This is the full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
//CURRENTLY UNFINISHED YET!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
void groupedData()
{
    int b = 0;
    int j;
    double numberOfClasses = 0;
    int i = 0;
    double arr[300];
    cout << "Will you specify number of classes (k) 1(yes), 0(no)?"<<endl;
    bool k_manual;
    cin >> k_manual;
    if(cin.fail())
    {
        cout <<"Invalid input."<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(k_manual == 1)
    {
        cout << "What is it?\n";
        cin >> numberOfClasses;
        if(cin.fail())
        {
            cout <<"Invalid input."<<endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    cout << "Enter grouped discrete quantitative data to calculate measures of central tendency and measures of variation.\nUse 0 to terminate.\n";
    cout << "======================================"<<endl;
    while (i < 300)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
        if (!cin.fail() && arr[i] == 0)
        {
            int classesK[150];
            if (numberOfClasses == 0)
            {
                numberOfClasses = ceil(1 + 3.3*log10(i));
            }
            for(j=0; j<= numberOfClasses; j++)
            {
                b += 1;
                classesK[j] = b;

            }
            double classWidthPrecession;
            cout << "Class width precession (1/0.1/0.01)?"<<endl;
            cin >> classWidthPrecession;
            //int arr[] = {1,2,3,3,2,5,4,4,3,1,2,1,4,6,5,5,4,2,3,2};
            cout << "\n\nCalculating..."<<endl;
            cout << "------------------"<<endl;
            //mean calculation

            double mean;
            double sum = 0;
            for (j=0; j < i; j++)
            {
                sum += arr[j];

            }
            mean = sum / i;
            cout << "\nMeasures of central tendency:\n----------------------------\n";
            cout <<"Mean(x_-): "<< mean <<endl;
            //median calculation
            sort(arr, arr + i, less<double>());
            if (!((i % 2) == 0))
            {
                int median_index = (i+1) / 2;
                double median = arr[median_index - 1];
                cout << "Median (x_~): " <<  median;

            }
            else
            {
                double median = (arr[i/2 - 1] + arr[i/2] ) / 2.0;
                cout << "Median (x_~): " <<  median;
            }
            //range calculation
            double range = arr[i-1] - arr[0];
            cout << "\n\nMeasures of variability:\n-------------------------\n";
            cout << "Range: " << range;
            sum = 0;
            for (j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                sum += pow((arr[j] - mean), 2);
            }
            double variance = sum / (i-1);
            double stdDeviation = sqrt(variance);
            double COV = (stdDeviation/mean) * 100;
            cout << "\nVariance_s2: " << variance;
            cout << "\nStandard Deviation: " << stdDeviation;
            cout << "\nCoefficient of Variation: " << COV << "%";
            //mean deviation calc
            sum = 0;
            for (j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                sum += abs(arr[j] - mean);
            }
            double meanDeviation = sum / i;
            cout << "\nMean Deviation: " << meanDeviation <<endl;
            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;


            int frqArr[150];
            double XiArr[150];
            for(j=0; j<150; j++)
            {
                frqArr[j]=0;
            }
            int k = 0;
//            for(j=0; j<i; j++)
//            {
//                if(arr[j] == arr[j + 1])
//                {
//                    frqArr[k] += 1;
//                    continue;
//                }
//                else
//                {
//                    k++;
//                    XiArr[k] = arr[j];
//                }
//            }
//            int cumArr[150];
//            int sumInt = 0;
//            for(j=0; j<=k; j++)
//            {
//                sumInt += frqArr[j];
//                cumArr[j] = sumInt;
//
//            }

            sort(arr, arr+i, less<double>());
            double classWidth = range/numberOfClasses;
            if(classWidthPrecession == 1)
            {
                classWidth = ceil(classWidth);
            }
            cout << fixed;
            cout << setprecision(3);

            double temp = 1.0;
            double ll = arr[0];
            double ul;
            double ulArr[150];
            double llArr[150];
            ul = (ll + classWidth) - classWidthPrecession;
            double num = classWidth;
            for(j=0; j<=numberOfClasses; j++)
            {
                ulArr[j] = ul;
                llArr[j] = ll;
                temp = 2.0;
                ll = ll + (temp-1.0)*(classWidth);
                ul = ul + (temp-1.0)*(classWidth);
            }
            b=0;
            k=0;

            for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
            {
                if((arr[j] >= llArr[b]) && (arr[j] <= ulArr[b]))
                {
                    frqArr[k]++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    b++;
                    k++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            frqArr[0] -= 1;
            int cumArr[150];
            int sumInt = 0;
            for(j=0; j<=k; j++)
            {
                sumInt += frqArr[j];
                cumArr[j] = sumInt;
            }
            cout << fixed;
            cout << setprecision(2);
            cout << "k\t\b|classes\t\t\t\b|Fi\t\t\b|FiXi\t\b|(Xi - X_)^2\t\b|Fi(Xi - X_)^2\t\b|Xi - X_|\t\b|Fi|Xi - X_|"<<endl;
            for(j=1; j<=numberOfClasses; j++)
            {
                //table output..........................
                cout<<classesK[j-1]<< "\t\b|" << llArr[j-1] << " - " << ulArr[j-1] << "\t\t\b|" << frqArr[j-1]<<endl;

            }
//            int frqArrSorted [150];
//            copy(frqArr, frqArr + k, frqArrSorted);
//            sort(frqArrSorted, frqArrSorted + k);
//            // cout << "\n\n" << frqArrSorted[k-1];
//            int largestFrq = frqArrSorted[k-1];
//            bool isMultimodal = 0;
//
//
//            for(b=2; b<=k; b++)
//            {
//                if(largestFrq == frqArrSorted[k-b])
//                {
//                    isMultimodal = 1;
//                    continue;
//
//                }
//                else if(!isMultimodal)
//                {
//                    break;
//                }
//            }
//            b = 0;
//            int ModeValIndex[150];
//            for(j=0; j<=k; j++)
//            {
//                if (frqArr[j] == largestFrq && !isMultimodal)
//                {
//                    ModeValIndex[0] = j;
//                    break;
//                }
//                else if(frqArr[j] == largestFrq && isMultimodal)
//                {
//                    ModeValIndex[b] = j ;
//                    b++;
//                }
//                continue;
//            }
//
//            if(isMultimodal)
//            {
//                cout << "\n\nModes are: " <<endl;
//                for(j=0; j<b; j++)
//                {
//                    cout <<  XiArr[ModeValIndex[j] + 1] <<endl;
//                }
//                if(b==2)
//                {
//                    cout << "\nMode is BiModal."  << endl;
//                }
//                else
//                {
//                    cout << "\nMode is MultiModal." << endl;
//                }
//
//
//
//            }
//
//            else
//            {
//                cout << "\n\nMode is: " << XiArr[ModeValIndex[0] + 1] << " (UniModal) " <<endl;
//
//            }
//

//            int max_frqArrVal = 0;
//            for(j=0; j<=k; j++){
//                if(frqArr[j] > frqArr[j+1]){
//                    if(frqArr[j] > max_frqArrVal){
//                            max_frqArrVal = frqArr[j];
//                            continue;
//                    }else if()
//                    else{
//                        continue;
//                    }
//
//                }else{
//                        continue;
//                }
//
//            }




            exit(0);


        }
        else if (!cin.fail())
        {
            i++;
            continue;

        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Wrong!"<<endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }



    }
}





int main()
{
//    cout << fixed;
//    cout << setprecision(2);
//    cout << 20.42 + 1.68*3 << endl;
    double range;
    double l;
    int k = 8;
    range = 32.17 -18.75;
    double classwidth = range/k;
//    cout << fixed;
//    cout << setprecision(2);
    l = 18.75;
    for(int n = 1; n<=k ; n++)
    {
        cout<< l << "                 classwidth: "<< classwidth<<endl;
        l += classwidth;




    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    l = 18.75;
    for(int n = 1; n<=k ; n++)
    {
        cout<< l << "                 classwidth: "<< 1.68 <<endl;
        l += 1.68;



    }
    //groupedData();


}
```

These are the test data that I use:

```
21.52
19.83
23.11
18.75
20.5
22.48
21.61
19.24
20.48
22.25
19.72
24.36
20.84
22.74
19.37
21.75
20.21
32.17
20.38
20.76
21.87
19.81
21.95
20.93
19.05
23.39
21.05
22.87
22.17
21.24
24.1
20.15
19.84
23.6
20.26
21.47
22.98
21.13
20.04
22.05
21.33
21.36
24.87
19.42
21.23
25.12
20.58
21.75
19.95
21.94
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: This is not a duplicate of that problem. This question does not ask why the error occurred. It asks for a solution for this specific problem and should be answered with a solution for this specific problem.

Comment: If you print out the value of `classwidth`, using more than two decimals, I'll bet it's close to but not exactly equal to `1.68`.

Comment: If two digits of precision are all you need and the ramge of int / long is sufficient, calculating in hundredths and dividing by 100 for output only could be an option. If that does not work, using some kind of BigMath library and working with that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is true, because I set the precision to only include 2 decimal points.
That's why I expected it to behave like the 1.68 value.

Comment: When you display the value, you *round* it. The value you display is just not the actual value you use in your calculations inside the loop. So what is actually wrong, the displayed value or the value you use in your calculations in the loop? Both can't be right, since they're different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh I see, so what do you propose to do so that the rounded displayed value is the same one that is used for calculations?

Comment: I figured a way, and it's so easy!

Comment: ```
double rounderFunction(double request, int decimalPlaces){
    double newNum;
    double shiftAmount = pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    newNum = round(request * shiftAmount) / shiftAmount;
    return newNum;

}
```

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

(32.17−18.75)/8 is 1.6775, not 1.68, so it is unclear why you would expect 1.68 to maintain accuracy.

To avoid accumulating rounding errors in a loop, recalculate the value from scratch in each iteration instead of adding to a previous value:

```
double start = 18.75, end = 32.17;
for (int n = 0; n < k; ++n)
{
    l = start + (end-start)*n/k;
    cout << l << endl;
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue, you see this program is supposed to calculate classes in statistics, so the bigger program accepts all the data, then automatically calculates classwidth, range and k.
That being said you are saying that I should declare a variable end is not really an option because this variable is to be correctly calculated by the program and I shouldn't be able to know it.
In other words, I only know the start value. And imagine if variable k was 1000? we wouldn't know the end.

Comment: @Ahmad: Edit your question to add details defining how class width, range, and k are determined.

Comment: I will do but It's fairly big and a little complicated.

Comment: @Ahmad:  Re “declare a variable end is not really an option”: The only variables I show being declared are `start` and `end`, and your sample code starts with these values as given, not calculated. There is no impediment to defining a variable to hold a given value. If you do not wish to define new variables, simply replace `start` in the code by `18.75` and `end` by `32.17`.

Comment: I'm sorry this is on me I should've included the complete program. I included it in the post as you requested.

Answer (score -1):

So I finally found an answer, which relies on using this function to round every number that requires so:

```
double rounderFunction(double request, int decimalPlaces)
{
    double newNum;
    double shiftAmount = pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    newNum = round(request * shiftAmount) / shiftAmount;
    return newNum;

}
```

Comment: `request * shiftAmount` unnecessarily risks overflow for large `request`.